# How to add and remove validation field to yup.validationSchema

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

How to add and remove validation field to yup.validationSchema

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    password: yup
        .string()
        .label('Password')
        .required()
        .min(2, 'Seems a bit short...')
        .max(10, 'We prefer insecure system, try a shorter password.'),
    });
```

Answer (score 22):

for adding validation you can use concat, checkout the documentation here:

[https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedconcatschema-schema-schema](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedconcatschema-schema)

You can define your basic validation and add additional validations later on. Be carefully that you are just concat of the same type.

Example:

```
const requiredSchema = Yup.string().required();
const min2Schema     = Yup.string().min(2, 'Seems a bit short...');
const passwordSchema = Yup.string()
                 .label('Password')
                 .max(10, 'We prefer insecure system, try a shorter password.')
                 .concat(requiredSchema)
                 .concat(min2Schema);
```

All that schemas are .string() schemas.
You can just concat an object with objects, string with strings, number with numbers etc.

For making conditional validations, you can just add an inline-condition:

```
let isRequired = true;

const nameAndPasswordSchemaObject = Yup.object().shape({
    name: nameSchema.concat( isRequired ? requiredSchema : null ),
    password: passwordSchema,
});
```

The same goes for yup-objects:

```
const emailSchemaObject = Yup.object({
   email: Yup.string().concat(requiredSchema)
});

const validationSchema = nameAndPasswordSchemaObject.concat(emailSchemaObject);
```

I hope that helps.

About removing schemas I couldn't see anything in the documentation (but never needed it)

Comment: Solved my problem. Used it as such "formSchema = formSchema.concat(dateSchema);"

Answer (score 6):

For someone that looking for another approach, like dependent on value inside the schema itself

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

export const Schema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    name: yup.string().lowercase().required(),
    phone: yup.number().default(0).required(),
  })
  .when((values, schema) => {
    if (values.name === 'john') {
      return schema.shape({
        isHungry: yup.boolean().required(),
        food: yup.string().default('Pizza'),
      });
    }
  });
```